# Get the array sum of each column of each subarray

Tags: php, arrays, loops, sum, array-column

This is my array:

```
$array = [
    'HRI' => [
        [14157.72, 39140.94, 36383.66, 38508, 8424],
        [14157.72, 39140.94, 36383.66, 38508, 8424],
        [14157.72, 39140.94, 36383.66, 38508, 8424],
        [14157.72, 39140.94, 36383.66, 38508, 8424],
    ],
    'RHA' => [111562.5, 37880, 11364, 23719.5,  26705],
    'PBA' => [58816.26],
    'MPU' => [432]
];
```

I want to go through each subarray and get the sum for each column.

E.g.

For the sub array with the key `HRI`:

```
[HRI] => 
    Array (
        [0] => Array ( [0] => 14157.72 [1] => 10157.72 )
        [1] => Array ( [0] => 39140.94 [1] => 39140.94 )
        [2] => Array ( [0] => 36383.66 [1] => 36383.66 )
        [3] => Array ( [0] => 38508.00 [1] => 38508.00 )
        [4] => Array ( [0] => 8424.00 [1] => 8424.00 )
    )
```

expected output:

```
column 0:
  14157.72 + 39140.94 + 36383.66 + 38508.00 + 8424.00 = ?

column 1:
  10157.72 + 39140.94 + 36383.66 + 38508.00 + 8424.00 = ?
```

Comment: So you just want to print the sum from each sub array? Or do you want to print the numbers with the plus sign ?

Comment: I need to add the each sub array @Rizier123 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

Just loop through the array and get the sum of each sub array with [`array_sum()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php)

```
foreach($arr as $k => $v)
    echo $k . " = " . array_sum($v) . "<br>";
```

example input/output:

```
$arr = [
        [1,2,3],
        [4,5,6],
        [7,8,9],
    ];
```

output:

```
0 = 6
1 = 15
2 = 24
```

**EDIT:**

Since you updated your array structure, just use this:

```
foreach($arr as $k => $v)
    echo $k . " = " . array_sum(array_map("array_sum", $v)) . "<br>";
```

**EDIT 2:**

If you want the sum of each array of the sub arrays the you have to use two foreach loops like this:

```
foreach($arr as $k1 => $innerArray) {
    foreach($innerArray as $k2 => $v)
        echo "$k1-$k2 = " . array_sum($v) . "<br>";
    echo "<br><br>";
}
```

**EDIT 3:**

I think I finally see what you want: You just want to go through each sub arrays and get the sum of each column of the sub array:

```
foreach($arr as $k1 => $innerArray) {
    foreach($innerArray[0] as $k2 => $v)
        echo "$k1-$k2 = " . array_sum(array_column($innerArray, $k2)) . "<br>";
    echo "<br><br>";
}
```

Comment: working awesome i have updated my question if i have my array like above how can get my expected output at

Comment: Rizer im struggling with above array how can i fix that ?

Comment: @QuestionUser See my edit! Just refresh the page and see my updated answer

Comment: `HRI = 14157.72+39140.94+36383.66+ 38508.00+8424.00;
 HRI = 10157.72+39140.94+36383.66+ 38508.00+8424.00;` yes i need to add the sub array values like this `[0]` wants to be added alone and `[1]` want to add alone how can i do that ?

Comment: @QuestionUser ^ And what should I do with this?

Comment: please check my comments @Rizer

Comment: please check my question now ur answer is added all arrays in sub arrays

Comment: @QuestionUser So if I got you right you want to add up all arrays of the sub arrays individual, *right*? -> See updated answer if this is what you need/want

Comment: Sorry Rizer please check my updated question i need above answer `14157.72+39140.94+36383.66+ 38508.00+8424.00 = ?` check the array values want to add the the sub arrays individual of first value alone and second value alone now its working like `14157.72 +10157.72 = ?`.I think u understand please help me

Comment: do u got it ? sorry for troubling you

Answer (score 1):

```
$a=Array (
    'HRI'=> Array (14157.72, 39140.94 , 36383.66,38508, 8424 ),
    'RHA'=> Array (111562.5, 37880 ,  11364 ,23719.5,  26705 ),
    'PBA'=> Array (58816.26),
    'MPU'=> Array (432 )
);
$sumHRI=0;

foreach ($a['HRI'] as $key=>$value) $sumHRI+=$value;

echo "HRI=$sumHRI";
```

For the updated question:

```
  $a=[
    'HRI'=>[
        [14157.72, 39140.94 , 36383.66,38508, 8424],
        [14157.72, 39140.94 , 36383.66,38508, 8424],
        [14157.72, 39140.94 , 36383.66,38508, 8424],
        [14157.72, 39140.94 , 36383.66,38508, 8424],
        ],
    'RHA'=>[111562.5, 37880 ,  11364 ,23719.5,  26705 ],
    'PBA'=> [58816.26],
    'MPU'=> [432]
];

$sumArray=[];
foreach ($a as $k=>$bigArray){
    $sumArray[$k]=0;
    foreach($bigArray as $subArray) $sumArray[$k]+=array_sum($subArray);
    echo "$k={$sumArray[$k]}";
}
```

That is if I understood right, and you want the calculated sum. If you want to actually print the numbers and the sign +, it has to be added a string concatenation there somewhere.

Comment: Just now I noticed that you actually changed the array. I had the feeling you want the sum on all sub arrays... You actually want the sum of the sums of the HRI array?

Comment: Sorry Ovidu please check my updated question i need above answer 14157.72+39140.94+36383.66+ 38508.00+8424.00 = ? check the array values want to add the the sub arrays individual of first value alone and second value alone now its working like 14157.72 +10157.72 = ?

Comment: I see you update the request a lot. When you figure out what exactly you need, I will get back and try to help.

Comment: This will print the total sum for each string key.

Comment: The updated answer doesn't work https://3v4l.org/kkjjX

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to assume what your expected result is for `RHA`, `PBA`, and `MPU` because they do not share the same depth/structure as `HRI`.

You might like to leave the shallower subarrays unchanged. [Demo](https://3v4l.org/QZ2JD)

```
$result = [];
foreach ($array as $acronym => $rows) {
    foreach ($rows as $index => $row) {
        if (!is_array($row)) {
            $result[$acronym][$index] = $row;
        } else {
            foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
                $result[$acronym][$key] = ($result[$acronym][$key] ?? 0) + $value;
            }
        }
    }
}
var_export($result);
```

If you had consistently structured subarrays, then no conditional handling would be necessary.  After summing columnar data in each subarray, the output structure can be sensibly reduced by one level. The output will preserve the first level, acronymous keys and the lowest level numeric keys. [Demo](https://3v4l.org/VuTOk)

```
$result = [];
foreach ($array as $acronym => $rows) {
    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
            $result[$acronym][$key] = ($result[$acronym][$key] ?? 0) + $value;
        }
    }
}
var_export($result);
```

If you only want to target `HRI` for summing, then that is simpler. Iterate the row data, preserve keys as you store or overwrite values. [Demo](https://3v4l.org/ifeLB)

```
$hri = [];
foreach ($array['HRI'] as $row) {
    foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
        $hri[$key] = ($hri[$key] ?? 0) + $value;
    }
}
var_export($hri);
```